# What's happening with this bizarre screen?

Tags: support

[image: Bizarre screen]

I don't understand what's going on :(

It seems it's an April Fool's gag! UGH!!! And each time I have to click on the clock icon to restore normalcy.

Comment: Throwback to 90's. This might help: [How to disable “time travel” entirely?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325996/468333)

Comment: Though the mouse pointer trail is nice!

Comment: Wait a minute!! I don't have this cursor!! What the heck? This theme is buggy. In Chrome sparkles are there but not in firefox. Or  it is due to some settings.

Comment: You don't see a "sparkly" trail behind the mouse pointer which is what I should have written instead of cursor? I edited the previous comment.

Comment: Looks like they yanked it already?

Comment: yup looks like. But there's no update on MSE about this theme.

Comment: Is it April 1st already somewhere on the planet? (And the starry pointer vapour trails are working nicely in FF for me. :))

Comment: Looks like the clicking on the clock icon now functions as a toggle :)

Comment: I see the sparkles on both Firefox and Google Chrome. I wish they'd share the magic!

Comment: Not funny, and very unprofessional. And it's not April 1st.

Comment: @heynnema I think the thing was activated as soon as the first part of the world has reached April 1st (like AUS or NZ) and will last until no part of the world has that date (like Alaska). That ballparks to UTC-12 until UTC+12.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the this year's April Fool :-)

When viewing the page source, you get a hint:

```
...
<!--
                HAPPY APRIL FOOL'S FROM STACK OVERFLOW

              \/                    __/   .::::.-'-(/-/)
                     _/:  .::::.-' .-'\/\_`*******          __ (_))
        \/          /:  .::::./   -._-.  d\|               (_))_(__))
                     /: (""""/    '.  (__/||           (_))__(_))--(__))
                      \::).-'  -._  \/ \\/\|
              __ _ .-'`)/  '-'. . '. |  (i_O
          .-'      \       -'      '\|
     _ _./      .-'|       '.  (    \\                         % % %
  .-'   :      '_  \         '-'\  /|/      @ @ @             % % % %
 /      )\_      '- )_________.-|_/^\      @ @ @@@           % %\/% %
 (   .-'   )-._-:  /        \(/\'-._ `.     @|@@@@            ..|........
  (   )  _//_/|:  /          `\()   `\_\     |/_@@             )'-._.-._.-
   ( (   \()^_/)_/             )/      \\    /                /   /
    )  _.-\\.\(_)__._.-'-.-'-.//_.-'-.-.)\-'/._              /
.-.-.-'   _o\ \\\     '::'   (o_ '-.-' |__\'-.-;~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~~/   /\
          \ /  \\\__          )_\    .:::::::.-'\          '- - -|
     :::''':::::^)__\:::::::::::::::::'''''''-.  \                '- - -
    :::::::  '''''''''''   ''''''''''''':::. -'\  \     C. SWANSIGER
_____':::::_____________________________________\__\______________________
-->
...
```

You can toggle the theme between funny and back-to-normal with the clock icon in the upper right:

[image]

The cute *Fairy Dust Cursor* (and others) can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/tholman/cursor-effects